# CSS @font-face is not working properly (2nd Issue)

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

When I use my computer with Firefox or IE, the font doesn't work, only when using Chrome. Also, when I use my cellphone even with chrome, the font doesn't work.

Please consider my code below, with a huge help from Gerardo BLANCO.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Signika;
  src: url('cllean-directory/fonts/Signika-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('cllean-directory/fonts/Signika-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('cllean-directory/fonts/Signika-Regular.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Signika;
  src: url('cllean-directory/fonts/Signika-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'), url('cllean-directory/fonts/Signika-Bold.woff') format('woff'), url('cllean-directory/fonts/Signika-Bold.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Signika;
  src: url('cllean-directory/fonts/Signika-Light.ttf') format('truetype'), url('cllean-directory/fonts/Signika-Light.woff') format('woff'), url('cllean-directory/fonts/Signika-Light.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Signika;
  src: url('cllean-directory/fonts/Signika-Semibold.ttf') format('truetype'), url('cllean-directory/fonts/Signika-Semibold.woff') format('woff'), url('cllean-directory/fonts/Signika-Semibold.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}
  font-family: SignikaS;
}
```

Comment: can u maybe add some html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few mistakes on your part.
1) It is better to name all of you font families as one.
2) You need to declare its respective weight and style.
3) Personal one -> Always put the family first

Hope this helps

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Signika;
  src: url('fonts/Signika-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/Signika-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/Signika-Regular.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Signika;
  src: url('fonts/Signika-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/Signika-Bold.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/Signika-Bold.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}

p {
  font-family: Signika;
}
```

```html
<p>Hi</p>
<p style="font-weight:bold">Hi</p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved me so many hours hahahah. I'm pretty new to HTML and CSS, I'm learning as I go practicing. Now I learned another great thing. Thank you very much, and have an amazing day!

Comment: @ThiagoDiogenes you are welcome. It makes my day hearing people learning this art. Hope it all goes smooth. If not, you are in the best community for it going wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, another problem rose from this same issue hahahah. The font is displaying good on a Desktop Chrome, but the font isn't displaying on Firefox, Internet Explorer and even Chrome on Android. Do you have any idea of what it might be the problem?

Comment: @thiagodiogenes mm mm it could be easier if you show a live example and or code. Maybe make another question and tag me

Answer (score 0):

Use semi-colons
ex:-

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Signika';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('../fonts/signika-v8-latin-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local('Signika Regular'), local('Signika-Regular'),
       url('../fonts/signika-v8-latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/signika-v8-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/signika-v8-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/signika-v8-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/signika-v8-latin-regular.svg#Signika') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Gerardo's answer could solve the problem of my code. Thank you anyway for using your time to help me!